# PL/SQL getting error in user-defined exceptions in function

Tags: oracle, plsql

In my PL/SQL program I created three exceptions: `divide_by_zero`, `others` and one user defined `divide_by_one` but my user defined exception doesn't work. I created a block statement to handle each exception but I am getting below error as shown in the screenshot. Can anyone help me to identify the issue ?

**code:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
PACKAGE CALCULATOR AS 

FUNCTION DivNumber(divend IN Number, divend2 IN Number) RETURN NUMBER;

END CALCULATOR;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE
PACKAGE BODY CALCULATOR AS

FUNCTION DivNumber(divend IN Number, divend2 IN Number) RETURN NUMBER AS
 e_ZERO_DIVIDE EXCEPTION;

 BEGIN
-- the condition
  IF divend2 = 0 THEN 
    Raise e_ZERO_DIVIDE; 
  ELSIF divend2 = 1 THEN
    Raise one_divide;
  END IF;
  return divend / divend2;

--Exception handling  
EXCEPTION 
    WHEN e_ZERO_DIVIDE THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('Division by 0 or null');
    RETURN 1;

    WHEN one_divide THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('Division by 1 or null');
    RETURN NULL;

    WHEN OTHERS THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('ERROR: '||sqlerrm);
    RETURN 1;

 END DivNumber;

END CALCULATOR;
/

select calculator.DivNumber(12,1) from dual;
```

**outout:**

[image]

Comment: Do you see how you declared the identifier E_ZERO_DIVIDE to be an EXCEPTION, at the beginning of your function (in the declarations section)? You must do the same with ONE_DIVIDE.

Comment: @mathguy thank you so much.

Comment: There is already a `zero_divide` exception, so you don't need to define your own. Oracle will already raise it too, so you don't need to check for it. Also the "or null" in your debug messages is misleading.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare one_divide of type Exception  in the declare section, then only it will work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).